# How do I set QTextStream in header?

Tags: c++, qt

How do I set a new QTextStream in the header, like this

```
MainClass{
private:
    QTextStream out;
}
```

Then, in initialization set the file, so instead of

`QTextStream out(&file)`, I would hope for something like

`out.setFile(&file)`, but there's no .setFile in QTextStream

Answer (score 7):

I found that QFile is an QIODevice, so QTextStream::setDevice(&QFile) will work.

Thus, now I have

```
MainClass{
private:
    QTextStream out;
    QFile file;
    void writetoBuffer();
}

void MainClass::writetoBuffer(){
    file.setFileName("bingbong.txt");
    out.setDevice(&file);
}
```

Comment: '&QFile' looks wrong... Moreover, you cannot call a method outside of the class without a function, method, etc.

Comment: That was for the sake of brevity. I added much of the formality to get it running and I think it does help those wanting context.

Comment: Please do not write incorrect answers for the sake of brevity in the future. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Edit to say, "please be considerate of those seeking context?" The answer wasn't incorrect, it just only directly answered the question and thus left out the common formalities of a c++ program.

Comment: Using setDevice(&file) to specify file for QTextStream did not work for me(Qt 5.x)

Answer (score 2):

The most concise way: constructor [initialization lists](https://faculty.cs.niu.edu/%7Emcmahon/CS241/Notes/constructor_initializer.html)

```
MainClass{
    public:
        MainClass( QFile& file ) : out( &file ) {}
    private:
        QTextStream out;
}
```

Comment: I like this as it's informative, however, it's not as direct as I just found.